# Ruby installation with rbenv fails on WSL2 with openssl/openyaml error

Tags: ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby in Windows using Windows Linux Subsystem and rbenv following [these instructions](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#ruby).

```
$ rbenv install 3.0.1
Downloading ruby-3.0.1.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.0/ruby-3.0.1.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.0.1...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210423)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20210428105920.7360.VTYCTG
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20210428105920.7360.log

Last 10 log lines:
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
The Ruby yaml extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Try running `apt-get install -y libssl-dev libyaml-dev` to fetch missing dependencies.

Configure options used:
  --prefix=/home/skarcher/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1
  --enable-shared
  LDFLAGS=-L/home/skarcher/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib
  CPPFLAGS=-I/home/skarcher/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/include
```

Nothing more helpful in the log -- it looks like most of the install is working and the error *seems* quite straightforward, but libssl-dev and libyaml-dev are installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libyaml-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libyaml-dev is already the newest version (0.2.2-1).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I couldn't find any reference to this issue other than posts referring to rbenv on Mac OS with older ruby versions. Any help/thoughts much appreciated.